# While Running AWS Athena query Query says Zero Records Returned

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

```
SELECT * FROM "sampledb"."parquetcheck" limit 10;
```

Trying to use Parquet file in S3 and created a table  in AWS Athena and it is created perfectly.
However when I run the select query, it says "Zero Records Returned."
Although My Parquet file in S3 has data.

I have created partition too. IAM has full access on Athena.

Answer (score 0):

If your specified columns names are correct, then you may need to load the partitions using: `MSCK REPAIR TABLE EnterYourTableName;`. This will add new partitions to the Glue Catalog.

If any of the above fails, you can create a temporary Glue Crawler to crawl your table and then validate the metadata in Athena by clicking the 3 dots next to the table name. Then select `Generate Create Table DDL`. You can then compare any differences in DDL.